# Can't get mathjax directive to wok in Angular2

Tags: angular, mathjax

I am having trouble getting the `MathJaxDirective` givin by [Thierry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36370826/how-to-get-mathjax-working-with-angular2) to work.

I always get the following strange error message:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:27 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/angular2/core(…)(anonymous function) @ localhost/:27
No errors in the server log. Any thoughts on what the trouble might be?

Two refs:

https://github.com/jxxcarlson/manuscripta2/blob/mathjax/app/directives/mathjax.directive.ts#L5 -- used this to import js as opposed to ts code

https://github.com/jxxcarlson/manuscripta2/blob/mathjax/app/app.module.ts#L27 -- If comment this out, no errors, but also no MathJax functionality

Comment: Adding a live sample exhibiting the problem might be a good idea, cf. [this one on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/epnc0r3rqVJhAt0LXmcG?p=preview).

Comment: I studied the plunker example at [Thierry's code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36370826/how-to-get-mathjax-working-with-angular2).  All working now.  For those interested, the code of the angular2 + mathjax project is at [github](https://github.com/jxxcarlson/manuscripta2b/releases)

Thanks so much!