# Using MathJax inside Typescript/Angular2 component

Tags: angular, typescript, import, global, mathjax

I'm having trouble calling the MathJax.Hub functions in my angular2 component. I have struggled over this for many hours last night. I need to call the MathJax API to re render some InnerHTML string that is dynamically binded. The problem is, no matter how I import the MathJax module or npm install it, I can't access the MathJax global variable in my component.ts. I verified this with trying MathJax.version and the compiler complains about can't finding version of undefined.

I have run npm install MathJax in my module. Run npm install @typings mathjax. Have tried importing mathjaxdirective. In the sample HTML provided upon mathjax install, I can see that formatting is correctly applied. What is the right way to gain access to the MathJax global variable inside my typescript?

Comment: Might this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36371349/1339651 otherwise you'll need to share what you've tried.

Comment: Allen, did you find a solution for this? I'm struggling with the same.

Comment: @AkashAgrawal Sorry for the super late reply, but yes I figured it out. PM me or something.

Comment: @AllenH., thanks for your response I really appreciate it, but I was able to get this working lately. :) Happy Coding!

Answer (score 4):

I found a simple solution. It as follows:

1. Add the following code in **index.html**

   ```
       <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
           MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
       </script>
       <script type="text/javascript" async
               src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML">
       </script>
   ```
2. Add this line in your typescript file as an import:

   ```
       declare var MathJax:any;
   ```
3. Use mathjax:

   ```
       MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);
   ```

Comment: I am trying to declare MathJax into angular context as a variable

Answer (score 1):

According to the article [Supports MathJax in angular2 with TypeScript](https://ruinshe.github.io/2016/05/31/development/support-mathjax-in-angular2/)

> If we use data binding through Angular2 and doing rendering on UI side, we may find that the MathJax text is not rendered. That’s because we need to re-render the string value every time we change it.
>
> There is a simple module example to handle with, which use event handler binded and will be trigered when value changed.
>
> ```
> import { Directive, ElementRef, OnChanges, Input } from "@angular/core";
>
> declare var MathJax: {
>   Hub: {
>     Queue: (param: Object[]) => void;
>   };
> };
>
> @Directive({ selector: "[mathJax]" })
> export class MJD implements OnChanges {
>   @Input("mathJax") private value: string = "";
>
>   constructor(private element: ElementRef) {}
>
>   ngOnChanges() {
>     this.element.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.value;
>     MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, this.element.nativeElement]);
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> On the template HTML file, we can use this directive like this:
>
> ```html
> <div class="math-element" id="equation" [mathJax]="equationTexString"></div>
> ```
>
> On the other hand, remember add the MJD directive into the component directive list:
>
> ```
> @Component({
>   selector: "equation-component",
>   directives: [MJD],
> })
> export class EquationComponent {
>   private equationTexString: string = "";
> }
> ```